# image watermark on an image in android

Tags: java, android

i have an image in imageview , how can i add an image/logo watermark on that image.?
i have used following code to add text watermark

```
     String watermark ="Sari collage";
     int x =1500;
     int y =1200;
     int color = Color.parseColor("#ff720b");
     int alpha=80;
     int size = 70; 
     boolean underline= false;

    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());



    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);




    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: why.?
i need to add an image as watermark..!

Comment: Why dont you try to Use a FrameLayout contain a Image and a TextView or ImageView to achieve it?

Comment: if you canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint), you can also drawbitmap

Comment: can u give me some piece of code please...!

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

```
String watermark ="Sari collage";
     int x =1500;
     int y =1200;
     int color = Color.parseColor("#ff720b");
     int alpha=80;
     int size = 70; 
     boolean underline= false;


int w = src.getWidth();
int h = src.getHeight();

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());


Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, w/2, h/2, null);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(color);

paint.setAlpha(alpha);
paint.setTextSize(size);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: u should always guess :p